# bluetooth serial device detect COM port #

Tags: windows, serial-port, bluetooth

I am pairing to or connecting to a Bluetooth device that has a serial port service associated with it. Is is possible to determine the COM port it registers too? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the following C# WMI code seems to do the job. But is this reliable?

```
        string deviceid = string.Empty;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher ( "Select * from WIN32_SerialPort" );
        foreach ( ManagementObject port in searcher.Get () )
        {
            string name = port.GetPropertyValue ("Name" ) as string;
            string provider = port.GetPropertyValue ( "ProviderType" ) as string;
            if ( provider == null )
            {
                deviceid = port.GetPropertyValue ( "DeviceId" ) as string;
            }
        }
```